# Spring security LDAP success handler

Tags: java, spring, authentication, spring-security, ldap

I have tried to implement a success handler for login using Spring security with LDAP in my web app. After searching online, the only way I found was to implement a custom user details mapper like so:

```
public class CustomUserDetailsMapper extends LdapUserDetailsMapper{

private static final String ROLE_NORMAL_USER = "Normal User";
private static final String ROLE_ADMIN = "Administrator";
@Override
public UserDetails mapUserFromContext(DirContextOperations ctx,
        String username, Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authority) {
    UserDetails originalUser = super.mapUserFromContext( ctx, username, authority );


    originalUser.getAuthorities();

    Set<AndaAuthority> roles = EnumSet.noneOf(AndaAuthority.class);

    roles.add(AndaAuthority.ROLE_ADMIN);

    for (GrantedAuthority auth : authority) {
        if (ROLE_NORMAL_USER.equalsIgnoreCase(auth.getAuthority())) {
            roles.add(AndaAuthority.ROLE_USER);
        } else if (ROLE_ADMIN.equalsIgnoreCase(auth.getAuthority())) {
            roles.add(AndaAuthority.ROLE_ADMIN);
        }
    }

    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getCredentials();

    User newUser = 
            new User( 
            originalUser.getUsername(), 
            originalUser.getPassword() != null? originalUser.getPassword():"", 
            originalUser.isEnabled(), 
            originalUser.isAccountNonExpired(), 
            originalUser.isCredentialsNonExpired(), 
            originalUser.isAccountNonLocked(), 
            roles );

            return newUser;
}
}
```

This was working - when I put a breakpoint here it stopped. But, is there a better way to implement a handler for such a case? I mean, the whole authentication part is done "under the hood" and I cannot really debug if something goes wrong and this method is not called, I have no other way to know where something went wrong on the way.

Thank you

Comment: It's not clear what your question is as you don't actually say what you are trying to do. Also, what do you mean by "under the hood"? You can add a breakpoint in any Spring Security class just as easily and it is trivial to add the source code to your project in an IDE. So it's not true that you can't debug. From Java's perspective it's just another part of your application.

Comment: I am trying to override the default onSuccess or something like that from Spring security to know when the login was successful/or not and to do different operations in each case.

Comment: Well, it still generally depends on exactly what the "operations" are. You can use an `AuthenticationSuccessHandler`. You'll find that described elsewhere on the site and in the reference manual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone else wondering:
You must declare your success handler as a bean so you can link it in your Spring security configuration.

The implementation from  [here](http://thinkinginsoftware.blogspot.ro/2011/07/redirect-after-login-to-requested-page.html) works well, 
you only have to declare your `authentication-success-handler-ref` in your `<form-login>` configuration tag and override the `onAuthenticationSuccess` method.

Other better solutions may exist, but this is the one that I found and worked in my case.